# How to exclude apostrophe from JSON array?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to output the following PHP script to output a JSON array that does not include apostrophes around the values because they are numbers.

**Using the code below I keep getting the following output:**

```
[{"name":"person1","sumValue":"200"},{"name":"person2","sumValue":"100"},{"sumTotal":"300"}]
```

The following is the PHP script I currently have that creates the array seen above. Numbers should not have "" around them and should instead look like this

```
[{"name":"person1","sumValue":200},{"name":"person2","sumValue":100},{"sumTotal":300}]
```

**What can I change in the script to get this result?**

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql =  "SELECT name, SUM(value) as numvalue 
         FROM Table1
            LEFT JOIN Table2 USING(DevName)
         WHERE name <> '' 
         and name is not null
         GROUP BY name";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // you want an array of objects, so create an object to sum the sub totals
    $total = new stdClass;
    $total->sumTotal = 0;

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);

        $total->sumTotal = bcadd($total->sumTotal, $row->numvalue);
    }

    $resultArray[] = $total;
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the options parameters in your call to the `json_encode` method to change the encoding. According to the docs of `json_encode`:

> The encoding is affected by the supplied options and additionally the encoding of float values depends on the value of serialize_precision.

So, by the docs we have the constant `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, that:

> Encodes numeric strings as numbers. Available as of PHP 5.3.3.

And your code would be:

```
$resultArray[] = $total;
echo json_encode($resultArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Here you find the full documentation:

https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Answer (score 1):

MySQL (via PHP, maybe other languages as well) tends to return all values as strings, so if you want them to be numerics, you need to cast them as such.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    // Cast the numvalue
    $row->numvalue = (int)$row->numvalue;         

    $tempArray = $row;
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);

    // Summing the values is as easy as this (which also will return a numeric value)
    $total->sumTotal += $row->numvalue;
}
```

If you really need to use `bcadd()`, then you need to cast that result as well since that function returns strings.

```
$total->sumTotal = (int)bcadd($total->sumTotal, $row->numvalue);
```

If you're expecting to get a float, change it to: `(float)` instead of `(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add [JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) to the json_encode:

```
$arr = [1,3,'abc', "34"];
json_encode($arr); // [1,3,"abc","34"]
json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); // [1,3,"abc",34]
```

So you would use

```
echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Answer (score 0):

the select return the values as string so

try cast properly the string as a valid number  ..  (in this case i use int but if you need  you can use floatval() for float  )

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $tempArray['name'] = $row['name'];
        $tempArray['numvalue '] = intval($row['numvalue']) ;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);

        $total->sumTotal = bcadd($total->sumTotal, $row->numvalue);
    }
```